# Как подключить шрифты в OceanWP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Нужно подключить левые шрифты в тему Wordpress. Может кто подсказать как? Описать алгоритм хотя бы? Тема: OceanWP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я хоть и не работал с Wordpress, но если там есть возможность загружать свои файлы на сервер, можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией в css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Zurich; /* создаваемое семейство шрифтов для использования на странице */
    font-weight: 400;    /* будет использоваться везде, где ширина шрифта будет нормальной */
    /* если не указано иных в дополнительных конструкциях, ширина всегда будет 400 */
    /* ширина может варьироваться от 100 (самого тонкого) до 900 (самого жирного) с шагом в 100 единиц */
    src: url("zurich.ttf"); /* собственно, ссылка на подключаемый файл шрифта */
    /* а теперь смотри внимательно */
    src: /* да, это обязательно нужно указать дважды, почему, я не знаю, но иначе не работает */
        url("zurich.ttf") format("ttf"), /* во втором src браузер уже смотрит все остальные форматы */
        url("zurich.otf") format("otf"); /* если не поддерживает из первого */
}
```

Если такой возможности загружать свои файлы нет, то можно в url вставлять внешние ссылки, на тот же google fonts, допустим, и браузер будет подгружать уже файлы оттуда

Ну и просто ещё раз, без комментариев, для чистоты кода

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Zurich;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("zurich.ttf");
    src:
        url("zurich.ttf") format("ttf"),
        url("zurich.otf") format("otf");
}
```